# Can anybody share the ebook link of Manubhashya of Medhatithi Part II (English Translation)?

Tags: resource

I got Part I to V except for part II. The translator of the book is Ganganath Jha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manusmrti with the Manubhashya of Medhatithi (translated by Ganganath Jha) has 10 volumes. The first two volumes contain Sanskrit verses. The English translation is present in the 3rd to 7th volumes. These five volumes are also known as Part I to Part V. 8th-10th volumes have some additional notes. Here I have added the links to the important volumes (3rd to 7th). All pdfs are good and the scan quality is excellent.

1. [Volume 3](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.46009)
2. [Volume 4](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.46010)
3. [Volume 5](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.46011)
4. [Volume 6](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.46012)
5. [Volume 7](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.46014)

Answer (score 3):

The all 12 chapters of Manubhashya are available [here](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi) online.

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, I am looking for a pdf version, which I can annotate freely and can have in my library and read offline.

Answer (score 2):

Manusmriti Bhasya of Medhatiti Vol 2 has 2 parts. You can download them [here](https://archive.org/details/in.gov.ignca.8239) and [here](https://archive.org/details/in.gov.ignca.8240/page/n3/mode/2up).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. Unfortunately, the scan quality is too bad. It is hazy. Anyway.